# What is SQL NULL value converted to for java primitive type char?

Tags: jpa, jdbc, char, nullable

What is SQL NULL value converted to for java type char? For example,

```
public class Foo {

    private char color;
}
```

The filed is primitive type, mapped to CHAR(1) in database. When the column is null, what should the color be when reading the column into the field?

UPDATE

When the field is not set(default value), and tried to insert a row using JDBC

```
String sql = "insert into foo (id, color) values (?, ?)";

PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
stmt.setObject(1, foo.getId());
stmt.setObject(2, foo.getColor());
stmt.executeUpdate();
```

ERROR

```
MySQL: java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xAC\xED\x00\x05sr...' 
for column 'color' at row 1

ORACLE: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type
```

Where is the value coming from?  Char type is not supported by JDBC?

Comment: since a char is not nullable then a sane JPA provider would not support a null value in that column (and would create a NOT NULL on the column if generating the schema). You don't say which JPA provider you are referring to.

Comment: JDBC itself has no support for (Java) `char`.

Comment: for Java, what is the default value for a field of char type if not set?  0 for number, false for boolean, what for char? from eclipse debugger, it displayed as a square symbol, but not able to see its byte value.

Comment: [This page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) says that Java's default value for a `char` field is `'\u0000'`.

Comment: ... but that appears to be irrelevant, at least for MySQL Connector/J, since I get the exact same error message when I try `stmt.setObject(2, 'x');`.